# Iterating over python files in a given directory and importing them?

Tags: python, dynamic, import, module

I'm working on a little pet project in python, and I want to be able to write external modules and dynamically import them. So far, I've got something like this:

```
def getModules(self):
    os.chdir(moduleDir)
    for module in os.listdir():
          #code goes here to import
          #also append to a list for use later on
```

I'd use `import module`, but that just gives a Syntax Error.

Comment: Did you try using "\_\_import\_\_" ?

Comment: try to use `importlib.import_module`, if your moduleDir is a package, use `pkgutil.walk_packages` to list all modules.

Comment: @hjfitz if you are satisfied with one of the answers, please accept them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) like this:

```
import importlib

my_modules = []

def getModules(self):
    os.chdir(moduleDir)
    for module in os.listdir():
          my_module = importlib.import_module(module[:-3])  # Or: module.split('.')[0]
          my_modules.append(my_module)
```

**Example:**

Let's say we have a module `a` that contains the following function:

```
def fn():
    print("Hello World")
```

The following is the result:

```
>>> import importlib
>>>
>>> my_module = importlib.import_module('a')  # Note: 'a' without '.py'
>>>
>>> my_module.fn()
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function. Something like this will help,

```
def getModules(self):
    modules = []
    os.chdir(moduleDir)
    for module in os.listdir('.'):
          m = __import__(module.split('.')[0]) # Assuming your listdir() gives .py files
          modules.append(m)
```

A still better choice would be [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) which is a wrapper around `__import__`. It's got a similar syntax to `__import__`. Of course, you need to `import importlib`.